# firebase firestore presence system

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to implement a presence system, I have followed the documentation for it. it works as it updates both my firestore and realtime databases. However, when i close the app, the realtime database is updated, while the firestore is not. below is the sample code I have in my cloud function, which I assume performs the action.

```
        const functions = require('firebase-functions');
        const admin = require('firebase-admin');

        admin.initializeApp();

        const firestore = admin.firestore();

        exports.onUserStatusChanged = functions.database.ref('/status/{uid}').onUpdate(
            async (change, context) => {

              const eventStatus = change.after.val();

              const userStatusFirestoreRef = firestore.doc(`users/${context.params.uid}`);

              const statusSnapshot = await change.after.ref.once('value');
              const status = statusSnapshot.val();
              console.log(status, eventStatus);

              if (status.last_changed > eventStatus.last_changed) {
                return null;
              }

              return userStatusFirestoreRef.set({
                online: false,
                last_changed: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              }, { merge: true });
            });
```

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what you've done to debug this function.  What exactly is it doing if not what you expect?

Comment: What do you mean by saying you 'assume [it] performs the action'? Also, this is a Cloud Function that you deploy. Once you deploy it, it is triggered when the RealTime Database updates the indicated reference, and I understand you do that through your app. I have made some minor changes to your code to test it and both databases are updated every time the function is triggered.

Comment: can you show me the changes you made. Also, the trigger works, however, when i close the app the real time database is updated to false, while the firestore database is still online.

Comment: I just adapted your code to my data, but the changes are just the following: `firestore.doc(``users/${context.params.uid}``);` to `firestore.collection('users').doc(eventStatus);`, and `firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() to `admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`. I understand you update the Real time database with your app, and that triggers the Cloud Function. Did you try triggering the function by modifying a value manually in your Real Time database? That would confirm my suspicions about the issue residing in the code of your app instead of the Cloud Function.